# How to add .pac files?

Tags: gnome-terminal, proxy, synaptic

I have got a proxy auto-configuration script which works on browsers and not on synaptic or cli. 
any idea where to put the proxy.pac file so that i can use the terminal / synaptic for internet access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in console:

```
 export http_proxy='http://full_URL_to_pac_file'
```

for synaptic / apt - add the following lines to /etc/apt/apt.conf

```
 Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port";
 Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://username:password@proxy:port";
```

Comment: btw, empathy does not seem to work even after adding the proxy.pac file